# username changes when launched under IIs and published

Tags: asp.net

I found a strange bug in programm( or may be not bug, I don't know)
I am writing asp.net web application and have standart asp.net database for profiles membership and security.
so when I write something like this

```
qwe.text=Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

Let's say our username  is John ,so 
I press ctrl+ F5 and launch my webapplication and see:

```
qwe.text = "John"
```

It's okay. But then I configure Iis , Publish my project.
Go to the same page and guess what I see:
`qwe.text = " John"` with whitespace character before John .
i tested it on another names the same effect.
I am a little bit  confused , what may cause such a nice bug.
It's like magic ,not programming..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET return User.Identity.Name from auth Cookie, It has been set by your Authentication module.

1. The auth cookie in http request/response can be modified by other system(browser, proxy, IHttpModule, IIS) between network process.
2. Your Authentication module for IIS / local environment may be different. check out Web.Config `<httpModules>` contains any one of them